# Snowflake - OBJECT data type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake OBJECT data type provides support for storing semi structure data (Primarily key value pairs), for example, if below is my dataset (with Parameter being of type OBJECT),

```
DeviceID, Parameters
D1, { "P1": "100", "P2": "150" }
D2, { "P2": "125", "P3": "200" }
```

it can flattened out by using, `SELECT DeviceID, Parameters['P1'], Parameters['P2']` and the output would be,

| DeviceID | P1 | P2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | 100 | 150 |
| D2 | 125 | 200 |

However if I want to have the individual elements as rows, what is the best method to do this, like if I need the output as below,

| DeviceID | ParmeterID | ParameterName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | P1 | 100 |
| D1 | P2 | 150 |
| D2 | P1 | 125 |
| D2 | P2 | 200 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CTE for data:

```
WITH data(DeviceID, Parameters) as (
    SELECT column1, parse_json(column2) from values
        ('D1', '{ "P1": "100", "P2": "150" }'),
        ('D2', '{ "P2": "125", "P3": "200" }')
)
```

you want to use the [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) function, wrapped in a TABLE or LATERAL:

```
SELECT 
    d.DeviceID,
    f.key::text as p1,
    f.value::number as P2
FROM data as d,
    table(flatten(input=>d.Parameters)) f
```

gives:

| DEVICEID | P1 | P2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | P1 | 100 |
| D1 | P2 | 150 |
| D2 | P2 | 125 |
| D2 | P3 | 200 |